# What determines when etherscan will automatically verify a contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, etherscan

As I understand it, etherscan will look at the bytecode and automatically verify contracts similar to ones its seen before. My question is, how does it make this decision? Does it verify only contracts where the bytecode is exactly the same as a previously submitted one? If so, where is this information stored? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we upload a code to etherscan, etherscan convert that code to bytecodes and verify that bytecodes with one on the blockchain if both match, it mark that code as verified otherwise you will face issues in verifications.

Now because the same contracts always have the same bytecodes, maybe they have some algorithms that detect the same bytecodes very fast or they have some storage thing, but this is the internal process that they did not tell in docs.